# TFS 2012: show "Queue new build" dialog with TFS API

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk

I was wondering if it is possible to call the "Queue build" dialog through the TFS API. I've looked on the internet, but there I can only find how to queue a build directly(without showing the "Queue new build" dialog) with the TFS API.

Info: We are currently on TFS 2012

Here you can find a screenshot of the "Queue Build" Dialog of which I'm talking about
http://support.smartbear.com/images/support/kb/data/2009/12/1/Queue_Build_Dialog.gif

Thanks

Kind Regards,
Michaël

Comment: Shai Raiten has a great blog about using the TFS API. Maybe this can help you: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/01/24/tfs-api-part-34-build-basic-actions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that dialog is a UI element of team explorer and not part of the API per say. The API is just some client classes that wrap the web services.

I'm pretty sure you'd have to write that dialog yourself and back it up with the right API calls to populate the controls and perform the queue operation when you press the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the assembly: **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.dll**.

This assembly is normally located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio XX.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\

There is a class "**DialogQueueBuild**" in namespace "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls".
This is what you're searching for.